# How does the consular officer decide whether to grant a 1-year or 5-year F1 visa to Chinese students?

Tags: usa, student-visa, chinese-citizens

I read  on [bu.edu/isso](https://www.bu.edu/isso/2018/06/11/changes-to-visa-length-for-some-chinese-students/#:%7E:text=While%20most%20Chinese%20nationals%20began,officer%2C%20now%20receive%20a%20multiple):

> The U.S. Department of State (“DOS”) has issued guidance to consular officers in China that could result in shorter visas for a small number of Chinese students beginning June 11, 2018. While most Chinese nationals began receiving a multiple-entry F-1 student visa for a maximum of five years beginning November 14, 2014, graduate students who are studying in major fields related to robotics, aviation, and high-tech manufacturing may, **at the discretion of the consular officer, now receive a multiple entry visa for a shorter 1-year time frame**.

How does the consular officer decide whether to grant a 1-year or 5-year F1 visa to Chinese students?

Comment: USCIS doesn't issue visas. US visas are issued by US consulates and embassies, which are part of the Department of State.

Comment: @user102008 thanks, fixed

Answer (score 2):

The main source of information I can find is [this AP news article](https://apnews.com/article/82a98fecee074bfb83731760bfbce515) from May 2018, which says:

> The State Department did not provide specifics. But a U.S. official
> said that according to instructions sent to U.S. embassies and
> consulates, Chinese graduate students will be limited to one-year
> visas if they are studying in fields like robotics, aviation and
> high-tech manufacturing. China identified those areas as priorities in
> its “Made in China” 2025 manufacturing plan.